# Rails sessions stored in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session

I have a page that shows a list of events. When the event is clicked it takes you to a login page and it keeps the session id along with the page. When I go to the next page it always sends the last session variable.

```
<% @events.each do |e| %>
<%= link_to e.event_name, sessions_new_path %>
<%= e.event_start %> - <%= e.event_stop %>
<% session[:event_id] = e.id %>
<%= session[:event_id] %>
<br>
<% end %>
```

This shows the session[:event_id] is there and it is storing in the variable but when I click on the link it will send the last session[:event_id] of the loop. Any ideas would be helpful. I am looking at option of either passing the variable to the next page or storing it into a database cell, but not sure on how sessions are stored in databases.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using a supported database with ActiveRecord, you can configure your application to store sessions in the database by editing your_app/config/initializers/session_store.rb:

```
YourApp::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
```

make sure to comment out or remove the line:

```
# YourApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_your_app_session'
```

Further, there are auth gems that handle redirecting users to protected pages after signing in. If you haven't already, look at [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and/or [authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic). Personally, I prefer Devise.